# How to add matrices generated through manipulations on three lists in R?

Tags: r

I currently have three lists `List.1`, `List.2`, and `List.3` which each contains 500 matrices, each of which has dimensions `100 x 100`. Hence, `List.1[[1]]` is a matrix of dimensions `100 x 100`.

The manipulation I would like to do is to see which of the elements for a given matrix in `List.2` is between the corresponding matrix and elements in `List.1` and `List.3`. The manipulation [is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50314792/how-to-check-if-each-value-in-a-matrix-is-between-the-corresponding-values-in-tw/50317782#50317782) the following for one matrix in the 3 lists:

```
+(List.2[[1]] < List.3[[1]] & List.2[[1]] > List.1[[1]])
```

which returns a matrix of 1's and 0's, with 1 for an entry being if the condition above was satisfied and 0 if it wasn't.

I would like to then do this over all 500 matrices in the list, without having to resort to loops. Is there a way to do this with the `Reduce` or `lapply` function, or both?

So far what I have is:

```
zero.one.mat <- List.1[[1]]-List.1[[1]] # Create empty zero matrix

for(i in 1:500){
  zero.one.mat <- zero.one.mat + +(List.2[[i]] < List.3[[i]] & List.2[[i]] > List.1[[i]])
}
```

which obviously isn't the most ideal way to do it. Any thought would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list.1 <- list()
list.2 <- list()
list.3 <- list()

N=5
list.1[[1]] <- matrix(1,nrow=N, ncol=N)
list.2[[1]] <- matrix(2,nrow=N, ncol=N)
list.3[[1]] <- matrix(3,nrow=N, ncol=N)
list.1[[2]] <- matrix(-1,nrow=N, ncol=N)
list.2[[2]] <- matrix(-2,nrow=N, ncol=N)
list.3[[2]] <- matrix(-3,nrow=N, ncol=N)
list.1[[3]] <- matrix(rnorm(N*N),nrow=N, ncol=N)
list.2[[3]] <- matrix(rnorm(N*N),nrow=N, ncol=N)
list.3[[3]] <- matrix(rnorm(N*N),nrow=N, ncol=N)



list.result <- lapply(1:length(list.1), FUN=function(i){list.2[[i]] < list.3[[i]] & list.2[[i]] > list.1[[i]]})
# [[1]]
# [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
# [2,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
# [3,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
# [4,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
# [5,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
# 
# [[2]]
# [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
# [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 
# [[3]]
# [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
# [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# [2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [4,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE


# If you need to fund the sum of all of them, then you can add Reduce:
Reduce("+",lapply(1:length(list.1), 
                  FUN=function(i){
                    list.2[[i]] < list.3[[i]] & 
                    list.2[[i]] > list.1[[i]]}))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    1    1    2    1
# [2,]    1    1    1    1    1
# [3,]    1    1    1    1    1
# [4,]    1    2    1    1    1
# [5,]    1    1    1    2    2
```